# Welcome menu in Eclipse product

Tags: eclipse, product

I have a product definition that depends on my feature. In my feature I have dependency on org.eclipse.ui.intro. However, when I launch product I don't see Welcome item in Help menu. What can cause welcome menu not to load?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dependency alone is not enough.

Did you follow all the steps required to define an intro?
See [Defining a minimal intro configuration](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_intro_minimal.htm), which echoes back that [old message](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.rcp/msg04239.html):

> You need to **register a Intro (aka Welcome) with a product** for you to be able to see it.
>   You need to run as a product.
>   When self hosting, you have to select "run a product" in the launch configuration and make sure you see and select your product from the combo.

So did you define a product binding for your intro (see e[**`org.eclipse.ui.intro`**](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_intro.html))?

Comment: Thanks VonC,

In my product definition I list defining product as a plugin that implements org.eclipse.core.runtime.products and org.eclipse.ui.intro extension points. One thing I am not sure about is if I have to define application in my product. Right now I have it as org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench. In the link that you referenced someone says "did you run your rcp app as an application or as a product?
you have to run as a product for the new Welcome support to kick in.", so am I doing this correctly?

thanks!

Comment: @camokatu: I think you are doing it right, except the important part is the product binding in the org.eclipse.ui.intro extension point.

Comment: @VonC, if you don't mind I'll reference snippets of what I have, because it seems I have things correct but still no welcome menu: 
http://pastebin.com/8xxbtkLj

In product definition my product is listed as org.camokatu.product.integration_tools. I don't know if it's related, but I don't have dependency on org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal in my defining plugin.

thanks for your help!

Comment: @camokatu: the extract from your `plugin.xml` looks good. You then need the config part of the intro extension point, in order to the right content.

Comment: Hmm, if all my extension points are correct then may be this has to do with target platform I am using then. I use 3.5 as my base and 3.4 as my TP. When I launch my plugins in 3.4 Welcome menu is there, but not in 3.5. I did not think about it as being the problem, but that's the only thing that's left.

Comment: Actually tried product in Eclipse 3.4, but still no welcome menu. But it does work when I use launch configuration as oppose to my product, guess I am missing a comma somewhere :)

Comment: I tried defining my own Intro ID in product definition's 'Branding' page. However, it seems this takes me in a direction of creating my own welcome page, which I don't want to do. I want my welcome page to contain samples, intros from other contributing plugins like DTP and others. So if I bind my product to intro in introProductBinding element with introId as org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal and define org.eclipse.ui.intro.configExtension extension point with my pages, the universal intro which as I understand is like generic still doesn't show up. Angry. Sad.

Comment: @camokatu: I understand. At this point, you may need to look at other examples, like the intro of Eclipse itself which (I believe) is able to show elements from other contributing plugins.

Comment: thanks for your help VonC, I know where I stand now and have some idea of what I have to do.

Comment: @VonC, I needed dependency on org.eclipse.sdk in my product. However, I tried this when I was trying to make it work on linux and it didn't do anything. Tried on windows today and it works. Need to investigate on linux further, but at least it works!

Comment: @camokatu: great news! As soon as you have new elements in the comments, I will include them in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if your Welcome page is based on the intro.universal, you will have to add org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal to your product dependencies.